# Accessing MainFragments webview in another Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

My application has a main fragment which has a webview in it, the webview serves different local html files, that the user selects from other fragments listview. I have implemented the onclick listener on the list view but when I try to populate the webview with the file, the application crashes.

Check my code here

```
    package as.hif.smartlearnvtu;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Fragment;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.webkit.WebView;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.ListView;
 import android.widget.Toast;


public class NetLabFragment extends Fragment {
public static final String TAG = "netlab";
String[] netprograms ={
        "01 Simulation of three Nodes P2P Network",
        "02 Simulation of four Nodes P2P Network",
        "03 Simulation of Transmission of Ping Messages",
        "04 Simulation of Ethernet LAN-I",
        "05 Simulation of Ethernet LAN-II",
        "06 Simulation of Simple ESS",
        "07 Error Detection with CRC-CCITT",
        "08 Distance Vector Algorithm in C/C++",
        "09 Client/Server Using TCP/IP",
        "10 Messages Using FIFO's IPC",
        "11 Simple RSA Algorithm in C/C++",
        "12 Leaky Bucket Algorithm in C/C++"
};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_net_lab, container, false);


}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    final WebView myWebView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.webView);
    ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView3);
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, netprograms));
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Fragment fragment;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                case 1:
                case 2:
                case 3:
                case 4:
                case 5:
                case 6:
                case 7:
                case 8:   myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/dks.html");
                case 9:
                case 10:
                case 11:
                case 12:

            }

        }

    });

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you pass the selected url from your `NetLabFragment` to the parent activity, which in turn calls a method on your `MainFragment` to display in its `webview` rather than accessing the `MainFragment's` webview directly in the `NetLabFragment`. Check this link out for more information:

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Thanks a lot,for both replies

Comment: Why can't I access the web view of main fragment in netlab fragment..since both the fragments belong to same acitivty?

Answer (score 0):

From the information provided, I can tell your app is crashing because u are trying to find the web view which is not present in your `NetLabFragment`.What u really need to do is pass the url (which the user clicks) to `MainActivity` and from there to `MainFragment` where webview is present.

So first add `OnUrlSelectedListener` to your `NetLabFragment` and get the instance of it in `OnAttach` of fragment.

NetLabFragment:

```
OnUrlSelectedListener mCallback;

...

 public interface OnUrlSelectedListener {
        public void OnUrlSelected(String url);
    }

...

 @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallback = (OnUrlSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnUrlSelectedListener");
        }
    }
```

So now u are ready to communicate between two fragment via your activity.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements NetLabFragment.OnUrlSelectedListener{

....

public void onUrlSelected(String url) {
        // The user selected the Url from the NetLabFragment 
        //get instance of Mainfragment by using id and call its method LoadUrl to load the url

        MainFragment mainFrag = (MainFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_fragment);

        mainFrag.LoadUrl(url);

    }

}
```

Pass the url to the `OnUrlSelected` method in your OnItemClick in `NetLabfragment`.

NetLabfragment:

```
....

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

//get the url from the position parameter

mCallback.onUrlSelected(url);
```

Comment: If that is the case,why don't it give me a syntax error while using findview by id

Comment: Because it is syntactically correct.Id is just a static randomly generated integer which u can find in R.java